# Massive primary key edition for disordered primary key column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sqlite, postgresql

I have a database with some tables, each with `ID` primary key column. All `ID`s contain huge random numbers like `827140014`, `9827141241`, etc. What is the easiest way to edit and change this values for chronological, starting from 1 (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc.)? Rows' order doesn't matter.

I want to do it for SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLite (there can be different solutions for each one).

Additionally suppose that there are some tables that depends on `ID` (foreign keys).

Comment: Are there any tables that reference the `ID` column?

Comment: No, but if it's possible I would like to know both solutions

Comment: For postgresql (I saw this initially in the postgres tag), if the values are the primary key, for a one off sort `cluster (tablename) on (tablename)_pkey` should sort the rows in that order. Note it will re-create the table and order the rows so it could take some time if the rows are in the millions. Other databases such as oracle and ms sql allow you to maintain primary key order with clustered indexes.

Comment: Lucas, `cluster` command only sorts rows physically on disk, it doesn't replace IDs.

Comment: This idea is completely nuts. Don't change the value of surrogates like that.

Comment: +1 @Denis Not clear what problem this solves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle solution: given table some_table with column id as primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE my_order AS SELECT id, rownum rn FROM some_table;
ALTER TABLE my_order ADD CONSTRAINT pk_order PRIMARY KEY (id);

UPDATE
  (SELECT t.*, o.rn FROM some_table t JOIN my_order o on (t.id = o.id))
SET id = rn;

DROP TABLE my_order;
```

You should be able to run something similar in PostgreSQL, just use analytic function row_number instead of Oracle's rownum. I'm not sure about other engines.

For referencing tables, just ensure that foreign key constraints are ON UPDATE CASCADE.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle

a). If there are tables referencing the table you want to update, first thing you have to do is to disable foreign key constraints. You can generate all the `ALTER` statements using below query:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || owner || '.' || table_name ||
       ' DISABLE CONSTRAINT ' || constraint_name || ';'
  FROM all_constraints
WHERE constraint_type = 'R'
  AND r_constraint_name = 
                        (SELECT constraint_name
                          FROM all_constraints
                         WHERE constraint_type = 'P'
                           AND table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
                           AND owner = 'OWNER_OF_THAT_TABLE');
```

b). Run the generated ALTER statements.

c). Next, you have to generate new IDs. You can either add new column to hold those values, or create a temporary table. New column approach:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME ADD temp_new_id NUMBER;
```

d). Populate the column:

```
-- Create a sequence to generate new IDs
CREATE SEQUENCE YOUR_TABLE_NAME_seq START WITH 1 CACHE 20;
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET temp_new_id = YOUR_TABLE_NAME_seq.nextVal;
COMMIT;
```

e). Update ID in each of the dependent tables in this manner:

```
UPDATE some_dep_table sdt SET sdt.master_table_id = 
  (SELECT ytn.temp_new_id FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME ytn WHERE sdt.master_table_id = ytn.id);
COMMIT;
```

f). Update your table - move IDs from temporary column to the actual column with ID:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET id = temp_new_id;
COMMIT;
```

g). Drop temporary column from your table:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME DROP COLUMN temp_new_id;
```

h). ENABLE constraints on dependent tables (use query to generate them from point a), just replace DISABLE with ENABLE).

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE table SET id = t.new_id

FROM (
    SELECT id as old_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id
    FROM table
) t

WHERE id = t.old_id
```

this will replace IDs with (1, 2, ...) and save their order.

Comment: And foreign keys get updated how, if there are no cascade updates?

Comment: Why would you do that without cascade updates? Obviously you should know what are you doing when you are changing primary key.